# Найти максимально значение в массиве объектов

Tags: c#, классы, объекты

Добрый день. Есть массив, в котором собранны ученики одного класса и надо найти самого старшего в классе по его персональному коду. Например,если его код 120399-12345 (string типа),то ему 19 лет на данный момент. Но как найти именно максимальное значение?

```
public void Max_vozrast()
{
    foreach (Uchenik a in ucheniki)//класс uchenik,массив ucheniki
    {
        string sub1 = a.pers_kod.Substring(4, 2);
        string sub2 = a.pers_kod.Substring(7, 1);
        int gs = 0;
        gs = Convert.ToInt32(sub2);
        int god = 0;
        god = Convert.ToInt32(sub1);
        int vozrast = 0;
        int voz_max = int.MinValue;

        if (gs == 2)
        {
            vozrast = 18 - god;
        }

        else
        {
            vozrast = 2018 - (god + 1900);
        }

        if ()//не понимаю какое условие должно быть,чтобы был выведен самый взрослый ученик
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Samiy starshiy");
            a.vivesti();//выводит информацию про него
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как то у вас все не правильно тут... К тому же вы работаете внутри цикла, где работать должны с 1 объектом коллекции... Но, хотите получить макс значение в коллекции, не правильно!

Comment: Мои глаза... А что, нельзя завести свойство `Age` (`Vozrast`, по-вашему) в классе?

Answer (score 0):

Создадим такой класс

```
class StudentCode
{
    //ctor
    public StudentCode(string stringData)
    {
        StringData = stringData;
        GetId();
        GetBirthday();
    }

    //исходная строка данных
    public string StringData { get; private set; }
    //иден.номер
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    //дата рождения
    public DateTime Birthday { get; private set; }
    //возраст лет
    public int Age => GetAge();

    //извлечение идент.номера
    private void GetId()
    {
        string val = StringData.Substring(7);
        Id = Int32.Parse(val);
    }

    //извлечение даты рождения
    private void GetBirthday()
    {
        //получаем дату
        string day = StringData.Substring(0, 2);
        string month = StringData.Substring(2, 2);
        string year = StringData.Substring(4, 2);
        string strData = day + "." + month + "." + year;
        Birthday = DateTime.Parse(strData);
    }

    private int GetAge()
    {
        //вычисляем возраст
        DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
        int age = now.Year - Birthday.Year;
        if (Birthday > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;

        return age;
    }
}
```

Тогда поработать с ним можно так

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> inputData = new List<string>
        {
            "120398-12340",
            "220399-12341",
            "120599-12342",
            "120397-12343",
            "101099-12344",
        };

        //входные строки преобразуем в коллекцию студ.кодов
        List<StudentCode> studentCodes = GetStudentCodes(inputData);

        //извлекаем самого старшего
        StudentCode studentCode = studentCodes
                                    .Aggregate((studCode1, studCode2) => studCode1.Age > studCode2.Age ? studCode1 : studCode2);

        Console.WriteLine($"У самого старшего возраст = {studentCode.Age}, его идент.номер: {studentCode.Id}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<StudentCode> GetStudentCodes(List<string> lines)
    {
        List<StudentCode> result = new List<StudentCode>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            StudentCode studentCode = new StudentCode(line);
            result.Add(studentCode);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: А нельзя как-то через массивы это же действие сделать?

Comment: @higque какое действие?

Comment: Нахождение старшего ученика. Как-то слишком сложно через списки получается. Или мой код не совсем корректный был?

Comment: @higque ваша попытка написать вычисление возраста (`vozrast = 2018 - (god + 1900);`, не говоря уже про это `if (gs == 2)
        {
            vozrast = 18 - god;
        }
`), как бы это помягче сказать, откровенная пурга.